# Can I prohibit an injection in Guice?

Tags: guice

I'm using a parent and child injector and I want to ensure I don't accidentally access a class in the parent injector that is meant to be bound in the child injector.  If the parent injector accesses the class, it could be bound automatically (and incorrectly because scope is important).

Is there a way I can force an automatic binding to fail in the parent injector, or at least report a run-time error?

For instance if I have a method `Foo` that is "illegally" requesting a Bar:

```
class Bar { @Inject Bar() {} } // Shouldn't be accessible in Foo's injector
class Foo { @Inject Foo(Bar bar) {} } // Binding should fail here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the only way to do this is to write a provider method for each prohibited class.  Each provider method would throw a runtime exception.

I've submitted an [enhancement request](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=716) to support doing this at bind time.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Binder doc:

http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html

`requireExplicitBindings()` may be what you need. By using the statement in your module, automatic Binding is disabled, only classes configured via `bind()` or `provides` are injected.

Comment: `skipSources` is meant for simplifying error output.  When you have binding errors, Guice won't report the provided classes in the calling stack.

Comment: Thanks for the info ... so its "all or nothing" (allow everything (default) or deny everything and explicitly add bindings), there is no "everything but ..." mode.

Comment: Yes, except that apparently you can limit this requirement on a module by module basis, but still it would apply to all classes.